# Leveraging scipy for matrix free finite elements

Tags: sparse-matrix, reference-request, scipy, hpc

This will be a very general question.

I have a 3D finite element code in Python which I would like to extend to handle "large" problems (~10^8 unknowns in the global system). Right now I am using the `scipy.sparse` library, which gives decent performance for iterative solvers, but I'm finding the following problems:

- I'm quickly running into memory limitations for problems larger than 10^6 unknowns
- The linear systems which I am solving are symmetric positive definite, but while `scipy.sparse` doesn't seem to have a storage format which knows about symmetry, so I think I am storing many more entries than necessary.
- Even before solving the global system, computing the element-local contributions (held in a multidimensional `numpy` array) are abutting the memory requirements.

Therefore, it seems clear to me that I need to either write my own matrix-free iterative solver, or to use an external library with that functionality. My questions:

- I understand that `scipy.sparse` wraps lower level routines such as lapack. What I need to write basically overloads sparse matrix vector multiplication. If I write this in Python (or maybe in C and wrap it with Python), do I have any hope of attaining decent performance, or is it simply necessary to be able to call these lower level libraries? I have no intuition for this, and don't want to spend 3 weeks writing my own matrix-free A*x routine which is too slow.
- Is it a good idea to write this routine in Python? Or do I need to write it in C and wrap it?
- Do there exist libraries which support this functionality? It seems unlikely, since a code-specific knowledge of how to compute A*x without assembling A would be necessary.
- Rather than write a matrix-free routine, could I write an out-of-core solver? Do such approaches scale to problems like mine?
- I have access to a cluster with many multi-core compute nodes. Eventually I would like to parallelize this implementation. Are there good tools or references for implementation guidelines?

Or is there a good way to handle the above while using only `scipy`? For example, is it possible to provide `scipy.sparse.linalg.cg` a pointer to a function which computes A * x (obviously the cg routine is limited by the A*x speed, but it would be nice to avoid coding CG, GMRES, etc. myself)?

Comment: I know trilinos has python wrappers that work well to supplement scipy/numpy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that `scipy` does indeed support this type of overloading.

One simply needs to write a class inheriting from `scipy.sparse.linalg.LinearOperator` and implement the `matvec` method.

Doing so allows use of all the `scipy.sparse` linear solvers, but with a matrix vector routine that can be implemented as the user desires (in my case, which applies each contribution independently and takes advantage of symmetry).

Answer (score 5):

I would say that the implementation + verification + unit testing would take you more than just 3 weeks. Although, if you are planning to invest that time, you might add that capabilities to `scipy.sparse` or [`scikits-sparse`](https://github.com/scikit-sparse/scikit-sparse).

Regarding symmetric sparse matrices, you can check [`Pysparse`](http://pysparse.sourceforge.net/index.html). It has [Sparse Skyline format (SSS)](http://pysparse.sourceforge.net/formats.html#sparse-skyline-format) that is used for symmetric matrices. You can also directly use the [Low-Level Sparse Matrices](http://pysparse.sourceforge.net/spmatrix.html) that they provide.

This package is used by [SfePy](http://sfepy.org/doc-devel/installation.html#requirements) that is a FEM package for Python.